# ShieldUI Grid: Grid with remote json data

Tags: shieldui

I've been trying to get the Grid to work with remote json data source; its been unsuccessful. Does anyone have sample code that I can compile and see work?

Tried copying and pasting code from the Shield UI site but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see some examples that connect to web services using the JSON data format:

[ShieldUI Grid - RESTful service](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service)

[ShieldUI Grid - OData example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-odata)

[Shield UI DataSource - another JSON example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/datasource/remote-data)

And you can see the following documentation section for more information how to setup the DataSource to work with remote data:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource/javascript/api/settings/remote/read